# declare output parameter of table type in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I know that mysql functions / procedures can return tables, but I am wondering if it is possible to declare *output parameters* of table types? Or are they limited to only mysql primitive types?

Comment: Are you talking about tables or cursors?

Comment: @Álvaro: Either is fine.